# Cannot set lookAt position for camera with FirstPersonControls.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

```
// Init a perspective camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.001, 10000);

// Init free camera controls for default
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
controls.movementSpeed = 1;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.1;

// Add camera to scene
camera.position.set(3, 3, 3);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(camera);
```

I'm creating a demo scene with FirstPersonControls.js for my camera. Everything is good but the lookAt position of the camera, I cannot set up for it. `camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);` is not work. How can I handle this? Thanks for reading!
For further, Here is full code of my demoscene.

```
<!-- Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"></script>
<!-- Camera control -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls/FlyControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls/PointerLockControls.js"></script>
<!-- Event handler -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/KeyboardState.js"></script>
<!-- JS for HTML interface -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajs/index.js"></script>

<!-- THREE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set scene size
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth, HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
// WebGL's object
var container = null, renderer = null, scene = null, camera = null;
// Camera object
var controls = null;
// Statistic object
var stats = null;
// Time
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
// Keyboard
var keyboard = new KeyboardState();
// Target geometry
var mesh = null;
// Objects array for handling something (haven't known yet) in PointerLock camera
var objects = [];
var ray = null;

// Initialize WebGL
function initWebGL() {
    setupRenderer();
    setupScene();
    setupCamera();
    setupLight();
}

// Initialize renderer
function setupRenderer() {
    // Create the canva element
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor({
        clearColor: 0x999999,
        clearAlpha: 1.0
    });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    // Add the canvas into its container
    container = $('#canvas-container-1');
    container.append(renderer.domElement);
}

// Initialize camera
function setupCamera() {
    // Init a perspective camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.001, 10000);
    // Init free camera controls for default
    controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
    controls.movementSpeed = 1;
    controls.lookSpeed = 0.1;
    // Add camera to scene
    camera.position.set(3, 3, 3);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    scene.add(camera);

    // Init camera controls (get the checked radio input value)
    var chosenCamera = $('input[name=camera]:checked').val();

    // What will happen if $('input[name=camera]') value is changed
    $('input[name=camera]').change(function () {
        // Reload chosenCamera value
        chosenCamera = $('input[name=camera]:checked').val();

        // Camera controls
        if (chosenCamera == 0) { // Free
            controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
            controls.movementSpeed = 1;
            controls.lookSpeed = 0.1;
            // Add camera to scene
            scene.add(camera);

        } else if (chosenCamera == 1) { // Track ball
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
            // Add camera to scene
            scene.add(camera);

        } else if (chosenCamera == 2) { // First person
            // Add controls
            controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);

            ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
            ray.ray.direction.set(0, -1, 0);

            // Add camera to scene
            scene.add(controls.getObject());

            // Feature detection
            var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document ||
                    'mozPointerLockElement' in document ||
                    'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;

            if (havePointerLock) {
                // Object(s)
                var element = document.body;

                // Action for event listener below
                var pointerlockchange = function (e) { // Action for changes pointerlock
                    if (document.pointerLockElement === element ||
                            document.mozPointerLockElement === element ||
                            document.webkitPointerLockElement === element) {
                        controls.enable = true;
                    } else {
                        controls.enable = false;
                    }
                }

                var pointerlockerror = function (e) { // Action for pointerlock error
                    $('#instructions').html('Error!');
                }

                // Hook pointer lock state change events
                document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
                document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
                document.addEventListener('webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);

                document.addEventListener('pointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false);
                document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false);
                document.addEventListener('webkitpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false);

                // Ask the browser to lock the pointer
                element.requestPointerLock = element.requestPointerLock ||
                        element.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                        element.webkitRequestPointerLock;

                if (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    var fullscreenchange = function (e) {
                        if (document.webkitFullscreenElement === element ||
                                document.mozFullscreenElement === element ||
                                document.mozFullScreenElement === element) { // Older API upper case 'S'.
                            document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange);
                            document.removeEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange);
                            element.requestPointerLock();
                        }
                    }

                    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
                    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);

                    element.requestFullscreen = requestFullscreen = element.requestFullscreen ||
                            element.mozRequestFullscreen ||
                            element.mozRequestFullScreen || // Older API upper case 'S'.
                            element.webkitRequestFullscreen;

                    element.requestFullscreen();
                } else {
                    element.requestPointerLock();
                }
            } else {
                $('#instructions').html('Your browser doesn\'t seem to support Pointer Lock API');
            }
        }
    });
}

// Add lights to the scene
function setupLight() {
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 0, 0).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    pointLight.position.set(250, 250, 250);
    scene.add(pointLight);
}

// Initialize scene
function setupScene() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    render();
}

// Rendering
function render() {
    /* ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********
     Floor texture
     */
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/textures/grey-concrete-texture-01.jpg');
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorTexture.repeat.set(100, 100);

    // Floor material
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: floorTexture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    // Floor geometry
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200);

    // Floor
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    floor.position.y = 0;
    objects.push(floor);
    scene.add(floor);


    /* ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********
     Add sky box
     */
    var r = "models/textures/skybox/sky6/";
    var urls = [
        r + "px.png",
        r + "nx.png",
        r + "py.png",
        r + "ny.png",
        r + "pz.png",
        r + "nz.png"
    ];

    var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
    textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
    shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = textureCube;

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
        uniforms: shader.uniforms,
        depthWrite: false,
        side: THREE.BackSide
    });

    var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(7000, 7000, 7000, 1, 1, 1), material);
    scene.add(skybox);


    /* ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********
     Load A1 building
     */
    var building = null;
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
    jsonLoader.load('models/a1/A1.js', function (geometry, materials) {
        // Init material
        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        for (var s = 0; s < materials.length; s++)
            materials[s].side = THREE.DoubleSide;

        // Init mesh
        building = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, faceMaterial);
        building.scale.set(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001);

        // Add mesh to the scene
        scene.add(building);
    });


    /* ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********
     Axis
     */
    scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(10));

    (function loop() {
        update(loop);
    })()
}

// Update
function update(act) {
    // Variables for calculation of animation
    var delta = clock.getDelta(); // milliseconds

    // If the chosen camera is PointerLock
    if ($('input[name=camera]:checked').val() == 2) {
        controls.isOnObject(false);
        ray.ray.origin.copy(controls.getObject().position);
        ray.ray.origin.y -= 10;
        var intersections = ray.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersections.length > 0) {
            var distance = intersections[0].distance;
            if (distance > 0 && distance < 10) {
                controls.isOnObject(true);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update camera control
    (controls == null) ? {} : controls.update(delta);

    // Update renderer
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Loop
    requestAnimationFrame(act);
}
</script>

<!-- Assistant functions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Resize canvas
    function windowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    // Animation loop
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
    })();
</script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Init drawing
        initWebGL();

        // Window resize event
        $(window).resize(function () {
            windowResize();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="canvas-container-1"></div>

<!-- panel -->
<div id="panel" class="dock">
    <p class="pull"><b>Camera</b></p>

    <form id="pan" name="pan" method="post">
        <input id="free-camera" name="camera" type="radio" value="0" checked=""/>
        <label for="free-camera">Free</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="trackball-camera" name="camera" type="radio" value="1"/>
        <label for="trackball-camera">Track Ball</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="pointer-lock-camera" name="camera" type="radio" value="2"/>
        <label for="pointer-lock-camera">Pointer Lock</label>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- instructions -->
<div id="instructions" class="dock">
    <p class="pull"><b>Thông tin</b></p>

    <article>
        Đề tài nghiên cứu khoa học của nhóm sinh viên lớp ĐH Hệ Thống Thông Tin K5, trường Đại Học Công Nghiệp Hà Nội.
    </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

Comment: ok then you have to provide something more (codewise) jsfiddle maybe. The problem does not seem related to the controls.

Comment: I've update my full code of the demo into the question. It's quite long, I'm sorry. Thank for your ardor!

Comment: Well I suggested jsfiddle so I can run the code. Anyway there are several issues. Your createGeometry() function is named render(); (small issue) but you should not be calling update from inside this function. Then you keep adding cameras to your scene. You have at least two. One at the top and then one mode depending on the type of your controls. Then in your update function you create an empty object when the controls are not defined. Is that really required. Just use an if statement without creating the empty object. Take a closer look at the misc_controls_pointerlock.html example.

Comment: Thank you so much, gaitat! I'll reconsider my code carefully. So, where is the better place for me to put update() function?. I have no idea how does it affect to my scene.

Comment: I suggest studying either the above example or any other for that matter to see the correct order of things. Hopefully you are using the r58 release of three.js.

Comment: I call update from inside render() function because I want to directly take effects to 'building' object without changing it to a global variable. Maybe it's a bad idea. I do what you've suggested now. Thank you so much!

Comment: this can't work as the first person controls for three.js have their own model (lat/lon/phi/theta) & update the camera lookAt based on that. Setting the camera lookAt will only get overriden by the control update

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate it beforehand for initial position with

```
controls.lon = degrees;
controls.lat = someOtherDegrees;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, FirstPersonControls wants only look in backward of X axis, and :

```
camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

does not work for me too.

But I have succeeded with :

```
direction = camera.getWorldDirection().clone();
angle = direction.angleTo (new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0))  // Forward and X axis 
controls.lon = - angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

it works well for me.